# Things to know about Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, hybrid-mobile-app

I am new to Flutter and i am trying to do my school project(create an app) using Flutter. Thus I installed Flutter in my android studio(windows). I used to create app for android but not familiar with ios app. So, there are few questions that came into my mind.

1. Since Flutter is a hybrid framework, and it use DART programming language. So does it means that the coding that i created in android studio(windows), will work in the android studio(macOS)? Which i do not need to rewrite or edit the coding 2 times.What i worry now is i need to write the code for 2 times in 2 different way.
2. IOS app can only build in apple product? Because of the Xcode thing?
3. Currently i found out that Flutter is one of the way to build hybrid app. But i want to know more, normally how app developer create app for both android and ios?

Comment: 1. Hybrid app development only requires a single codebase. 2. You can develop an iOS app on a Windows or Linux machine using Flutter (there are guys here like Suragch who have done it). 3. Lower-budget projects that want iOS and Android use hybrid SDKs (like Flutter) but top-tier projects with money (or developers) will almost always go native. IMO, hybrid apps are good for lower and mid-level tier projects but if you want to build something truly epic, go native or go home.

Comment: @bsod Thankyou for your info and explaination, I learned a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have chosen the Flutter that is really great.

Android Studio is a tool or you can say editor which is useful to create flutter project. you can also user other tools too. So you don't need to do code again while switching the OS from windows to MacOS. All you need to do is just setup Android Studio properly and open/import project. That's it

This is obvious. iOS is an Apple Product and build for Apple Device.

You need to explore official site for the same to get more idea. [Flutter Dev](https://flutter.dev/)

Comment: Yes, Almost code will be same, Happy Fluttring